# Chrome I JavaScript issue regarding change of display properties in css

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-browser, styles

I have been working with some JavaScript to change display properties for my website. it works fine for Firefox and IE, but Chrome and Safari do not respond at all. I am trying to change the display from "none" to "block", or the reverse.  Here is the code:

```
 function setStyleClass (classesOff,classesOn) {
    var classOn;
      if (document.all) {
        for (var s = 0; s < document.styleSheets.length; s++) {
  for (var r = 0; r < document.styleSheets[s].rules.length; r++){
    if (document.styleSheets[s].rules[r].selectorText.indexOf(classesOff,0) > -1) {
        document.styleSheets[s].rules[r].style.display = "none";
        }
      for(var j = 0; j < classesOn.length; j++){
               classOn = classesOn[j];
          if (document.styleSheets[s].rules[r].selectorText == '.' + classOn) {
              document.styleSheets[s].rules[r].style.display = "block";
            }
        }
      }
  }
 }
else if (document.getElementById) {
 for (var s = 0; s < document.styleSheets.length; s++) {
  for (var r = 0; r < document.styleSheets[s].cssRules.length; r++) {
    if (document.styleSheets[s].cssRules[r].selectorText.indexOf(classesOff,0) > -1) {
        document.styleSheets[s].cssRules[r].style.display = "none";
            }
      for(var j = 0; j < classesOn.length; j++){
               classOn = classesOn[j];
        if (document.styleSheets[s].cssRules[r].selectorText == '.' + classOn) {
            document.styleSheets[s].cssRules[r].style.display = "block";
            }
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

When this is called, it is given a list of style id's to turn off, and styles to turn "on".
Here is the call:

```
 onClick="setStyleClass('book','book2_nl','book3_nl','book4_nl','B1_List_01_20','B1_Link_21_40']);
```

The way this works is to turn "off" any styles with "book" in the name, as well as, book2_nl, book3_nl, and book4_nl. The last two styles get turned "on". So I am replacing one "list of links to pages" with another, different list. The code above works fine in IE and FF, but does nothing at all that I can see in Chrome and Safari.
the styles all look like this coming in:

```
.B4_Link_21_40    {
display:  none;
color: #f8fb24;
font : 90% Book Antiqua;
}
.B4_List_21_40    {
display:  none;
color: #f8fb24;
font : 90% Book Antiqua;
}
```

I want to get these styles to turn on when I click the appropriate link. Are there any obvious errors in my code that could be causing this?

OK, you have seen the above question, now I have figured out how to go back and add html to this for your benefit :)

```
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>
<script> //the script posted above </script>
<style>
.book1 {
    position: absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:410px;
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    display: block;
}
.book2 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:450px;
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
}
.B1_Link_01_20 {
display: none;
color: #f8fb24;
font : 90% Book Antiqua;
}
.B1_List_01_20 {
display: block;
color: #f8fb24;
font : 90% Book Antiqua;
}
.B1_Link_21_40    {
display:  block;
color: #f8fb24;
font : 90% Book Antiqua;
}
.B1_List_21_40    {
display:  none;
color: #f8fb24;
font : 90% Book Antiqua;
}

</style>

<div align="justify" align="center" class="mainBody"
<p>Here's some content...</p>
</div>

<div class="book1">
    <a href="#" target="_self"
    onClick="setStyleClass('book',['B1_List_01_20','B1_Link_21_40']);
    switchStyleClass('B2_Li');
    onMouseOut="window.status=''; return true;">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="book2">
    <a href="#" target="_self"
    onClick="setStyleClass('book',['B2_List_01_20','B2_Link_21_40']);
    switchStyleClass('B1_Li');
    onMouseOut="window.status=''; return true;">
    </a>
</div>

<div class="B1_List_01_20">
<a href=Link To Page 1.shtml>1. Link To Page 1</a><br>
<a href=Link To Page 2.shtml>2. Link To Page 2</a><br>
<br></div>
<div class="B1_List_21_40">
<a href=Link To Page 21.shtml>21. Link To Page 21</a><br>
<a href=Link To Page 22.shtml>22. Link To Page 22</a><br>
<br></div>

<div class="B1_Link_01_20">
<a ONCLICK="setStyleClass('B1_Li',['B1_List_01_20','B1_Link_21_40']);" href="#">List of Links 1 - 20</a><br><br>
</div>

<div class="B1_Link_21_40">
<a ONCLICK="setStyleClass('B1_Li',['B1_List_21_40','B1_Link_01_20','B1_Link_41_60']);" href="#">List of Links 21 - 40</a><br><br>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: 1. You're not using JQuery, which would make your code take 5 lines at maximum. 2. Your `else if` has a [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) without passing any `id` to it, which most likely returns a compiling error. 3. Your `onclick` function call is passing a closing `]` as if it were an array, but there's no opening bracket! 4. You're passing more parameters than the function accepts, thus anything past the 2nd parameter gets automatically discarded. Either rewrite your code according to @ryan or show us some html.

Comment: Thank you Fabricio. I'm not much of a programmer at all, so I have no experience with JQuery. I take your point, and would love to have simpler code. Checking back to my code, the opening [ seems to have been dropped in the copy to this forum. The opening brackets are all there. With that, I am passing 1 parameter to turn off, and a list to turn on. Glad to show html, will add that below. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Yes, add some of your HTML to the question, it will automatically bump your question to the top. :P

Answer (score 2):

First if your just trying to change links then I would put the different links in 2 containers positioned in the same place via `position: absolute` then I would have one with a default style none. When the button is clicked then you don't even have to pass anything to your method since your only dealing with 2 containers and you know both their id's.

Then instead of going though the style sheets, just use `document.getElementById('container_1').style.display = 'block';`
`document.getElementById('container_2').style.display = 'none';`

As long as your container is a block level, such as a div, then this will change their display  property in every browser.

if you want to do it through changing their class names then you could do this.

```
function changeStyles(){
    document.getElementById('container_1').className = 'classOn';
    document.getElementById('container_2').className = 'classOff';
    //rest of your javascript
}
```

*This is still assuming you go with two containers instead of trying to change every link's individual style

**Edit:**

So not knowing what html you actually have makes it harder to answer your comment but here goes.

Your html could look something like this:

```
<div class='classOn' id='container_1'>
    <a href='some_link'>some link</a>
    <a href='some_link2'>some link2</a>
    <a href='some_link3'>some link3</a>
    <a href='some_link4'>some link4</a>
</div>
<div class='classOff' id='container_2'>
    <a href='different_link'>different link</a>
    <a href='different_link2'>different link2</a>
    <a href='different_link3'>different link3</a>
    <a href='different_link4'>different link4</a>
</div>
<button onclick='changeStyles()>See new Links!</button>
```

Then your css:

```
.classOn{
     display: block;
     position:absolute;
     margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
     //rest of your css
}
.classOff{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    //rest of your css
}
```

Notice how both classes have the exact same margin, they can have this because of the absolute position attribute. It effectively takes the space they would be using out of the page. now when the function `changeStyles()` is called by pressing the button the first div is hidden and the second div shows up with the new links in the exact same position. hope that helps.

Ok so my example above works fine with what you have just make `class='classOn'` your `class='B1_List_01_20'` and make `class='classOff'` your `class='B1_Link_21_40'` and use the function above and it should switch between them just fine.

Comment: Thank you Ryan. I am not terribly fluent in Javascript, so your approach seems good, and simple, which is good. I actually have several "lists", to be put into containers. I don't quite follow your example with the name changing, and all of the css that follows each call. I will add some html to provide a more complete example of the code I presently have. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MarkBahlke updated the answer to try and answer your comment.

Comment: Hi Ryan, I'm trying to work with your suggestion, and having some difficulty. I am sure that it's me. The difficulty is filling in the blanks around your suggestions with the rest of my content. My overall "system" is larger than the example I gave of course. I have 4 "books", each with a long list of links to content which I want displayed 20 links at a time. I am trying to understand how to put the different containers or objects into this scheme according to what you have here. I also see that you are using "id's" which I have not done. Can you please fill in a few more blanks for me?